# Anyway to programmatically make the tiles in a tile map able to switch positions with one another?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm a college student who is relatively new to iOS development and SpriteKit specifically. I've created a tile map that generates tiles with random images and was curious if there was a way to programmatically make these tiles able to swap positions with one another when the user has touched the two respective tiles (think Bejeweled). The following is my createTileMap() function called when the user touches a specific node in the scene:

```
    let tileSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: labelsHolderShape!.frame.width / 9, height: labelsHolderShape!.frame.width / 9)

    // These are the tiles loaded into the tile map
    let appleTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Apple"), size: tileSize)
    let bananaTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Banana"), size: tileSize)
    let coconutTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Coconut"), size: tileSize)
    let grapesTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Grapes"), size: tileSize)
    let orangeTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Orange"), size: tileSize)
    let pearTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Pear"), size: tileSize)
    let watermellonTile = SKTileDefinition(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Watermellon"), size: tileSize)

    let fruitsTileGroupRule = SKTileGroupRule(adjacency: .adjacencyAll, tileDefinitions: [appleTile, bananaTile, coconutTile, grapesTile, orangeTile, pearTile, watermellonTile])

    let fruitsTileGroup = SKTileGroup(rules: [fruitsTileGroupRule])

    let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: [fruitsTileGroup], tileSetType: SKTileSetType.grid)

    let tileMap = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: 8, rows: 8, tileSize: tileSize, fillWith: fruitsTileGroup)

    tileMap.zPosition = 3
    tileMap.alpha = 0

    addChild(tileMap)
    tileMap.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.75))
}`
```

I would assume I have to work within the touches began/moved methods or possibly recode my createTileMap function altogether?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Tilemaps allow for alternative tiles,  I do not know how to do it, but you may want to look into using that.